# Calculate point on a line if the slope is known

Tags: php, math, geometry, cartesian

Trying to compute the left and top of a page element.

The element needs to be positioned on an imaginary line that runs from 0,0 of the page window to a point (roughly) equal to 425 pixels from the beginning of the line.

The slope of the line is -.375.

How can I calc the left and top using php?

Comment: Thanks, but actually, that was just an example. How could can I calculate that with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

In general:

[image]

Comment: $x = 425 * cos(atan(.375));
        $y = 425 * sin(atan(.375));

Comment: @dono Yes! Good! BTW .. read my comment on your question. Happy New Year!

Comment: Lovely illustrations - how did you generate them?

Comment: @duffymo http://www.geometryexpressions.com/ , I use it as a companion tool to Mathematica